# What can I do after a driver was built with newest Linux source codes?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I don't have Linux source codes corresponding to kernel image version of embedded system at my hand, which version is 4.19.57-v7+. I downloaded Linux source codes (git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) and then built it successfully (4.19.127):

cd linux

KERNEL=kernel7

make bcm2709_defconfig

make -j4 zImage modules dtbs

sudo make modules_install

Then, I built my wifi driver based on such version of Linux kernel (4.19.127) and succeeded. I then 'insmod' that .ko driver and got failure: invalid module format.

I know what it meant. Now, I have choices to procceed:

1. Update new my own built kernel to my embedded system. And then 'insmod' that .ko file.
2. Update my embedded system kernel version from 4.19.57-v7+ to 4.19.127 from git hub on Internet.
3. Download ver. 4.19.57-v7+ Linux source and then rebuild the wifi driver.

My trouble is now, for #1 & #2, I have no idea how to update my built kernel from Internet & local.
For #3, how can I download the old Linux source codes of version 4.19.57-v7+.

Besides, which way is the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose #1 and do the following:

> copy linux//dts/*dtb in development system to /boot in target system

> copy linux//overlays/dts/*.dtb in development system to /boot/overlays in target system

> copy linux//zImage in development system to /boot/kernel.img

Remember to do backup before updating all those files. It's option to add a line like 'kernel=zImage' into /boot/config.txt.

Then, reboot it and use 'uname -a' to confirm if the new kernle was boot.